# Warning! The maximum key length is 900 bytes. The index 'PK_AspNetUserLogins' has maximum length of 1800 bytes

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core

У меня есть сайт asp.net core на хостинге в appharbor и я не имею доступа к sql-серверу, чтобы сделать резервную копию в виде bak-файла.

Зато могу выбрать на базе пункт меню Task - Generate script и сохранить результаты в виде sql-скрипта со всеми create table и insert into. Но каждый раз когда я проверяю резервные копии (запускаю на другом сервере и смотрю, всё ли прошло успешно) я вижу странный warning в начале скрипта:

> Warning! The maximum key length is 900 bytes. The index
>   'PK_AspNetUserLogins' has maximum length of 1800 bytes. For some
>   combination of large values, the insert/update operation will fail.
>   Warning! The maximum key length is 900 bytes. The index
>   'PK_AspNetUserTokens' has maximum length of 1804 bytes. For some
>   combination of large values, the insert/update operation will fail.

И вроде как это не ошибка, а всего лишь предупреждение, но как-то не очень хочется по собственному недопониманию лишиться данных.

Так о чём всё же это предупреждение? Есть ли возможность потерять данные? Нужно ли может какие-то хитрые параметры выставить перед генерацией скрипта?

Sql сервер "там" версии 10.50.1600, а "тут" у меня версия 11.0.3128.0 - возможно это нужно как-то подчеркнуть.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ага, то есть он в таком случае именно не вставит строку в базу. Это плохо. С другой стороны я всегда смотрю на эти раздутые колонки asp.net core непомерной длины (под guid выделяется 450 символов, ха! или под nvarchar(max)) и думаю, о чём думали проектировщики... Так вот вопрос такой: а если мне вот вдруг кровь из носу нужен будет и индекс и запись с двумя полями по 450 строк (упаси господи от индексов по таким длинным строкам!) - то где крутить максимальную длину индекса?

Comment: @Yaant Ответы - в ответы ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

У Вас составной первичный ключ (он же, в случае MS SQL Server, кластерный индекс) состоит из двух колонок `nvarchar(450)`. То есть теоретически у Вас может случиться так, что Вам понадобится вставить в обе колонки значения максимальной длины, 450 символов. Поскольку каждый символ в `nvarchar` занимает 2 байта, длина такого ключа окажется (450+450)*2 = 1800 (+4 служебных байта). Но поскольку в индексе ключ может быть не более 900 байт, вставить такую запись сервер не сможет. Об этом он и предупреждает.

Следует отметить, что ограничение в 900 байт на ключ индекса жестко прописано в коде сервера и никак не настраивается.

Во избежание возможных проблем, можно рассмотреть возможность создания для данной таблицы суррогатного первичного ключа, и отдельных некластерных индексов на колонки (если они будут реально нужны, зависит от запросов).